# How many antiquarks can be squeezed inside a nucleon without upsetting exclusion principle?

Tags: particle-physics, quarks, pauli-exclusion-principle, color-charge, pentaquarks

I read about a nucleon with 3 Strange quarks which clearly violates PEP, however this was soon resolved by introducing colour charges. Then I read about colour confinement where surplus energy can be transformed into many pairs of quarks or even a pentaquark (4 quarks + 1 antiquarks), soon I imagine a neutron star must have tons of surplus of energy so may I suspect there are probably more than 3 colour charges? My question is how many quarks can be squeezed inside a nucleon?

Comment: a small request to all experts: please put in extra effort to explain in layman term because I really have a very hard time reading on this site thanks ;D

Comment: There is no limit on the number of quarks. There is a limit on the number of quarks that can be put into the same *spatial wavefunction.*

Comment: @BenCrowell: while I research spatial wavefunction, can you tell me a bit how nucleon tell each other apart? is it out of gluon range?